# objective-c check If a/some release(s) are forgot

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, release

Is-there a way to know if there are some NSString or pointer or something like that are not released/deleted when using ARC and which ?

Comment: Use Instruments with the "Leaks" tool ...

Comment: First use the static analyzer.

Comment: Yep I did it.But when i'm going to profile -> leaks , it seems there is another one and it seems came from a UILabel and initWithBytes. But I chech my codes I don't have any UILabel not released. Perhaps the storyboard ?

Answer (score 1):

In your xcode before run the project just click on the `Build And Analyze` option, which will tell you the warning and potential leak of your code.

Comment: Yep I did it.But when i'm going to profile -> leaks , it seems there is another one and it seems came from a UILabel and initWithBytes. But I chech my codes I don't have any UILabel not released. Perhaps the storyboard ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check specific objects, implement the -dealloc method to NSLog self, and implement maybe init so you can match the count.
In reality, you should first logically set up your code correctly. Off course you do that, so the next step is to use Instruments (leaks). Check out WWDC session on how to effectively use Instruments for that.